# enum is not working

Tags: jpa, enums

I have an entity class with an enum field. I am creating the db dynamically from the entities and I am using `orm.xml` as follows.

```
<basic name="relationshipType">
       <column name="Type"/>
       <enumerated>STRING</enumerated>
</basic>
```

In my db, the column `Type` is created as `int(11)` instead of `varchar`. But when I tried with annotation as `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`, I got a table with a `varchar` field.

Is there any thing I am missing in the orm.xml? I am using jpa 2.0 and hibernate 3.27. Please help.

Comment: I have same issue,did you solve it ?

Comment: not able to solve it yet.

Comment: @Suraj search ended here. https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7645

Comment: I was using hibernate 4.1.7.Final version when I updated it to 4.1.10.Final problem solved . Thanks to you. You can post this as answer